# How to make reaction auto role to single choice only

Tags: python, discord.py

I made an auto role with lots of roles to choose, but user can choose multiple roles. Is there a way to make this in to single choice only?

In this code I just made it 2, but I have like 10 of it.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    guild = discord.utils.get(self.client.guilds, name='Test')
    channel = self.client.get_channel(222222222)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(11111111111)
    assassin = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='sniper')
    rogue = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='medic')

    if payload.message_id == 1111111111:
        if str(payload.emoji) == "☠":
            await payload.member.add_roles(sniper)
            await message.remove_reaction("☠", payload.member)
            return

        if str(payload.emoji) == "":
            await payload.member.add_roles(medic)
            await message.remove_reaction("", payload.member)
            return
```

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to keep track of the role given to a user and remove it when they select a different role, or remove every possible role the user could have before assigning the selected role.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Problem with removing all roles before adding is they will remove the roles that can’t be obtain by reaction... Is there any other way?

Comment: Don't remove all roles, just remove the specific roles that can be given by your reactions

Comment: So write await payload.member.remove_roles one by one? Is there other efficient way of doing it?

Comment: You can pass all of you roles to `remove_roles` at once, This is the simplest way I can think of to achieve what you want without completely re-engineering your code